# Grails 2.3.4 Sorting / FindAll Changes

Tags: sorting, grails

In my application, I had been sorting my domain object as follows:

`def o = Domain.findAll(sort: 'lastUpdated')`

In Grails 2.2.* , this was working fine and the results were being returned. Today, I upgraded to Grails 2.3.4, and that same syntax is throwing an error, stating that:

`No property found for name [all] for class [sample.Domain]`

What's the new syntax for sorting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use list:

`def results = Domain.list(sort: "lastUpdated")`

Comment: This appears to work as well and is a bit shorter than what I was doing below. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 4):

About the last comment, it could create a pretty bad performances issue:

With `Domain.findAll().sort({lastUpdated: 'desc'})` you load the entire table before sorting anything. It looks ok for this request, but assuming that you have tons of data you would want to add a maximum and an offset. The request would take too much time otherwise.

On the other hand, the one above is much better:

```
def results = Domain.list(sort: "lastUpdated")
```

Doing so, you load only the amount of data you need... nothing more, nothing less. You can this way add an offset and a maximum of rows:

```
def results = Domain.list(max: 10, offset:10, sort: "lastUpdated")
```

It is not an answer to the original post, but it explains why the previous comment had a bad vote :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, as soon as I posted it, I figured it out: `Domain.findAll().sort({lastUpdated: 'desc'})`

Comment: To the person that posted a negative vote, please explain. Both this method and the one posted by zoran119 work and resolve to an 'ArrayList' type object. There are no functional differences as far as I can tell. Zoran's solution is a bit shorter, and so I am using that now, but I would like to understand your rationale behind the down vote.

Comment: Probably because you are doing all of your sorting yourself instead of letting your database do it, which would be wiser. Go with the `Domain.list(sort: "lastUpdated")`. That's the way to do it.